# Fragments, Services and UI: modular approch

Tags: android, android-fragments, plugins

The goal: create a modular app on which plugin must have UI (that's the key point). I have all info about the main app (the "server") and also about all plugin (all will be made by us).
So we want to give the main apk to user and let him acquire "modules" in order to increase main apk features. He will install the "module APK" which will became visible in the Server app and. Clicking on the module, the user would be able to use the GUI of the module to interact. Ideal would be to have at same time on screen GUI of the server and of the module.

Test 1: having a look at Services. Nice, comunication between the server and clients work fine, but it seems clients (so "Services") are made only for calculation, treatement and so on, but are unable to have form and display. So the "server" have the form, get the data, send them to the service which perfom action send back result and the server display. Impossible to have Activity in a "Service"?

Test 2: Fragment. Nice, but seems the Fragment must be in the same package than the "caller".

Test 3: iFrame. Nice as we can have UI from the Server and from the Client visible at same time and interact with the two. But seem the client class must be in the same APK.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Ideal would be to have at same time on screen GUI of the server and of the module.

Android does not have anything "out of the box" that implements this well. The closest is `RemoteViews`, but you have a limited palette of widgets to choose from and even more limited event handling capability.

> Impossible to have Activity in a "Service"?

Correct.

> Any idea?

You are welcome to create your own custom equivalent of `RemoteViews`. In the end, a `RemoteViews` is a `Parcelable` description of how to build a bit of UI. Your plugin would pass this to the host app by any number of possible IPC options, and the host app would be responsible for rendering it.

Comment: Does it mean the plugin will have the "data" of the UI, send them to the main app and that the main app will have to display and handle the UI? No way to have the "module" doing that???

Comment: @Peter: "Does it mean the plugin will have the "data" of the UI" -- sorry, but I do not know what you mean by this. You can think of it as the plugin sending HTML to the host, where the host then displays the HTML (which, BTW, is another option). "No way to have the "module" doing that?" -- the module can define what the UI should be, but it is up to the host to actually cause those widgets to appear.

Comment: Well let's have an other example: when you print under Windows or Mac OS, clicking on print open the driver. This is the driver which display the form, handle the request and send data to the printer. But the driver receive data from the app. From user point of view it "seems" the driver is a part of the app. But it's not. 
What you say is that in Android the "plugin" will have to send "UI code" to the App, the app will read theses "data" display the UI and handle it (RemoteView). That's it? So no way to do the same as with drivers on Mac?

Comment: @Peter: "This is the driver which display the form, handle the request and send data to the printer" -- perhaps Windows changed from the last time I printed from it, but the print driver does not provide the UI for the print dialog. The print driver provides details of what should go in that UI; the OS shows the UI. Windows has had options for one process to render in another's UI (e.g., OLE), which was proven to be a security disaster, same as with browser plugins (e.g., ActiveX).

Comment: "the OS shows the UI" of course. But the code to display and handle the UI (which button you click and so on) is in the driver not in the software (I've made drivers this way a few years ago, but perhaps things has changed). When you say " the module can define what the UI should be, but it is up to the host to actually cause those widgets to appear. " this mean the definition of the UI is inside the module but the code to display must be in the main app? As the code to check which button is clicked? :/

Comment: @Peter: "the code to display must be in the main app?" -- yes. "As the code to check which button is clicked?" -- yes.

Comment: Thanks VERY much!!

Answer (score 0):

See article about Hexagonal architecture: http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture. 
Service can launch Activity from it, but you have to allow it in manifest.
Different .apk files (different programs) run in separate processes, so you need to use Interprocess communication (IPC): https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html. 
There is a project on my work - store, which can download different apps. Every app is a separate apk.

Comment: I know Service can launch Activity. But the goal is to have the UI "inside" the Service. Not to launch an external one.